# Why am I getting UnknownFormatConversionException for the following String.format() code?

Tags: java, string, formatter

I was trying to put together a regex expression, which could use repeating patterns via a String format option.

```
String non_dot = "[^\\.]";
String dot     = "\\.";
String sfp1    = "%1$s*?%2$s";
String sf      = sfp1 + sfp1 + sfp1 + sfp1.substring(0,3) + "*";
System.out.println(sf);
String regex   = String.format(sf, non_dot, dot);
System.out.println(regex);
```

The output from printing `sf` is as follows:

```
%1$s*?%2$s%1$s*?%2$s%1$s*?%2$s%1$*
```

However, when it comes time to evaluate the `String.format(...)`, for the derivation of the `regex` variable, my code bombs with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2547)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2533)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2792)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:23)
```

I have been using these resources.

- [Java Formatter Class in API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [Excellent String formatting guide](https://www.journaldev.com/17850/java-string-format#java-string-format-argument-index)

According to that, it should work!

**Can someone spot why I am getting this error?**

Comment: I guess you want `sfp1.substring(0,4)`, not `sfp1.substring(0,3)`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica Code may be of use to others when you have repeating patterns in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JB Nizet's comment said: Your substring end bound is wrong, and as a result you have `%1$*` in your format string, which isn't a thing (it's missing an `s` after the `$`).